# Remove certain span tags, keep the text inside - Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the following html:

```
<h1>These are <span style="color: red;">RED</span> words</h1>
<h2>These are <span class="green">GREEN</span> words</h2>
<h3>These are more <span style="color: red;">RED</span> words</h3>
```

I want:

```
<h1>These are RED words</h1>
<h2>These are <span class="green">GREEN</span> words</h2>
<h3>These are more RED words</h3>
```

In other words, I want to use javascript or jquery to remove the just the `<span style="color: red;"></span>` but keep everything else. And the span tags have no id, just that style to distinguish them.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you only want to remove `span` tags that have a `style="color: red"` or do you want to remove span tags that have any style inlined? Or do you want to remove span tags that have a style inlined with no class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `unwrap()`. [Here](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) you can find the documentation. Also remember to check if the `span` has the property `style`.

```js
$('h1, h2, h3').find('span').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('style')){
      $(this).contents().unwrap();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>These are <span style="color: red;">RED</span> words</h1>
<h2>These are <span class="green">GREEN</span> words</h2>
<h3>These are more <span style="color: red;">RED</span> words</h3>
```

Comment: that's a good thing to know, but how would you select the text content in order to match the parent?

Comment: Nice! Maybe put in an if statement for .css ('color')

Comment: @Jtbs, yes, just added it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
$('h1').text($('h1').text())
$('h3').text($('h3').text())
```

Of course you still need logic to test if style exists on the span, just showing there is another way to remove the span and preserve text.